# Magento 2 - Module confliction

Tags: magento2, module, extensions, conflict

I am using ultimo theme in my Magento 2.1.3 and I have installed one of extension but both gets conflict as slideshow is not showing properly and after inspecting I have found classes added from the installed module.
When i disabled the module, its working fine.

Can anyone suggest how to resolve the confliction in Magento 2?

Comment: There was an issue with Owl Carousel Js and after disabling it, everything is working fine.